# How to refresh only a div, not the complete page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this code that selects the type of a restaurant. After selecting any type the page is refreshed and after some SQL processing I get all restaurants corresponding to the selected type and show it in Google Maps.

How can I do that without refreshing the complete page, like only refreshing the `<div>` containing Google Maps?

```
<select class="mapleftS" name="type" id="type" onchange="changeType(this.value)">
    <option value="0">كل الانواع</option>
    <?$type = mysql_query("select * from rest_type ");
    while($rod = mysql_fetch_array( $type )) {
        if($rod[id] == $_REQUEST['type'])
            $selll = 'selected';
        else {$selll = '';
    ?>
    <option value="<?=$rod[id]?>" <?=$selll?> ><?=$rod[name]?></option>
    <? } ?>                                            
</select>
<script>
    function changeType( id ) {
        parent.location = '?type=' + id;
    } 
    $(function() {
        var text_menu = $("#type option:selected").text();
        $("#ddddd_").html(text_menu);
    });
</script>
```

After selection this code is run:

```
if($_REQUEST['type']) {
// do some thing and refrsh map div
} else {
// do some thing and refrsh map div
}
```

And the following element contains Google Maps:

```
<div id="mppp" class="map"></div>
```

JS for Google Maps:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=SOMEAPIKEY&sensor=true"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
  var address_index = 0, map, infowindow, geocoder, bounds, mapinfo, intTimer;
  $(function (){
    mm();   
  });

  mm = function() {
    // Creating an object literal containing the properties you want to pass to the map
    var options = {
      zoom: 15,
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(24.701564296830245, 46.76211117183027),
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };

    // Creating the map
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('mppp'), options);
    infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

    //******* ARRAY BROUGHT OVER FROM SEARCHRESULTS.PHP **********
    mapinfo = [ <?=$da?> ];
    intTimer = setInterval("call_geocode();", 300);
  }

  function call_geocode() {
    if( address_index >= mapinfo.length ) {
      clearInterval(intTimer);
      return;
    }
    geocoder.geocode({
      location: new google.maps.LatLng(mapinfo[address_index][6], mapinfo[address_index][7])
    }, (function(index) {
          return function(results, status) {
            if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
              // Scale our bounds
              bounds.extend(results[0].geometry.location);
              var $id = mapinfo[index][0];
              var $tell = mapinfo[index][3];
              var $title = mapinfo[index][2];
              var $img_src = mapinfo[index][3];
              var img_src = mapinfo[index][1];
              var $logo = mapinfo[index][4];
              var $status = mapinfo[index][5];
              var $sell = mapinfo[index][6];
              var $city = mapinfo[index][8];
              var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: new google.maps.LatLng(mapinfo[index][6], mapinfo[index][7]),
                icon: {
                  url : '<? bloginfo('url'); ?>' + img_src  + '',
                  scaledSize : new google.maps.Size(50,50)
                },
                map: map,
                scrollwheel: false,
                streetViewControl: true,
                title: $title
              });
              google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
                // Setting the content of the InfoWindow
                if (img_src) {
                  var imdd = '<img src="<? bloginfo('url'); ?>' + img_src  + '" width="60" height="60" style="margin-left:4px;float:right;" />';
                }
                else {
                  var imdd = '';
                }

                if ($tell) {
                  var tell = 'رقم الهاتف : '+$tell+'<br>';
                }
                else {
                  var tell = '';
                }                               

                if ($status) {
                  var status = 'الحي : '+$status+'<br>';
                }
                else {
                  var status = '';
                }

                if ($city) {
                  var city = 'المدينة : '+$city+'<br>';
                }
                else {
                  var city = '';
                }

                var content = '<div id="info" style="direction:rtl;font:15px time new roman;font-weight:bolder;position:relative;width:210px;"><a href="#"><div style=" font-size:13px;font-family:Tahoma;font-weight:bolder;text-align:center;font-weight:bold">' + $title + '</div><br><div style="float:right">' + imdd + '</div><div style="float:right;text-align:right;font-family:Tahoma">' + tell + city + status + '</div></a><br /><a style="float:left;color:#d22f00;font-size:12px;font-family:Tahoma" href="<? bloginfo('url'); ?>/rest-det/?id=' + $id + '">المزيد+</a></div>';
                infowindow.setContent(content);
                infowindow.open(map, marker);
              });

              map.fitBounds(bounds);

              if (mapinfo.length == 1) {
                map.setZoom(12);
              }
            }
            else {
                // error!! alert (status);
            }
          }
        }
      )(address_index)
    );
    address_index++;
  }
  </script>
<div id="mppp" class="map"></div>
```

Comment: I modified your above code by adding proper indentation/making it look pretty.  It's much easier on the eyes now.  I would highly recommend using a "smart" editor, like Netbeans, for JavaScript development.  On top of the editor taking care of indentation for you, it can also give hints for bad practices that you're doing.  Also, having neat and organized code can help track down errors a lot quicker.

Answer (score 2):

You can use an AJAX pattern to refresh part of your page.

1. move your SQL code into another script - e.g. query.php
2. return a list of results in a JSON format
3. when the list changes call runQuery
4. use the function to parse the returned data and update your map

```
<script>
function runQuery() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "query.php?type="+ $("#type").val(),
        cache: false,
        success: function(data){
            // code to process your results list;
        }
    });
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an AJAX concept where you are able to change only a portion of your page without having to do a full page refresh or Postback.

You will find a ton of examples on what you are trying to do but the main concept is that you will:

-Take user input

-call back to your server with values

-have the server return you information that you then use to append or overwrite a portion of the page